# How to invert colors in preview pdf option of mozilla Firefox?

Tags: firefox, pdf

I prefer the preview in Firefox option for PDFs, rather than downloading PDFs and then viewing them. However the default white background on the preview hurts my eyes. So is there a way that I can: preview PDFs in Firefox without having to download them and with inverted colors?

p.s.: "Dark background and light text" extension for firefox does invert the pdfs and it is good. But my default global preferences for this extension are different. Is there a way to tell the extension to "always invert pdfs". I add this as a footnote, because a solution that doesn't rely on this method is also welcome.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for an extension like [this one](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/dark-background-light-text/).

It will make pages dark and text white, it even has some customization options and can be used on all pages or just one, I see no reason it would not work on PDF preview too, just open the menu and choose invert.

[image]

Comment: Yes that works. However my default global preferences for this extension are different. So every time I open the pdf I have to manually invert it. I don't see a way of telling the extension to "always invert pdfs". Do you know of a way?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

---

#### Method 1 (may not work)

1. Install [Stylus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/styl-us/).
2. Install [this style](https://userstyles.org/styles/158547/invert-pdf).

#### Method 2

1. Set `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` to `true` in [`about:config`](https://about:config) and create a file in `.../Firefox/Profiles/$PROFILE_DIR/chrome/userContent.css`.
2. Paste the following into `userContent.css`:

   ```css
   @-moz-document regexp("^https?://.*\\.pdf(\\?[^\\./]*)?$") {
     .pdfViewer .page {
       filter: invert(0.95) hue-rotate(180deg);
       border: 9px solid #00DEAD00 !important;
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: I installed both software you mentioned and now it says it doesn't support pdf: "Stylus can not access some file types (e.g. pdf & json files)."

Comment: @Pooya You can either 1. enable file access for Stylus or 2. directly copy paste the code snippet into your browser's userChrome.css and set `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` to `true` in `about:config`.

Comment: I do not feel comfortable giving a web browser extension access to files on my machine.